This error has been happening since I installed version 17.0.0 of Angular CLI "Error: The service was stopped: spawn C:
This error started when I installed Angular CLI 17, the ng serve command runs the program, but when I click to open the page in the browser this error appears in the terminal

from the limitted info, you could try npm cache clean delete node modules, delete package-lock, npm install. It can also be a privilege error, try to run it with elevated privileges. You can also try --verbose maybe there are more helpfull logs.

the path to this folder is very long, I did a test with a smaller path and the error stopped happening, could this be the problem? @Cristian-Alexandru SANDU

well, Windows has a limit of 260 characters for file paths and regarding url paths most browsers can handle more than 2k characters. I never saw somebody cross those limits before so can't say for sure if that would be the error if this happened. About the windows limit, i think that can be increased to something like 4k but not sure how.
